# Java object references in a database

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm developing a Java application and I would like to replace Collections by a SqLite database.
My question is: Can I store Java object references in a database? How?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't store objects, not in a standard *relational* database such as SqLite. For storing objects in a database you'd need an object oriented database. You may wish to look into [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Comment: No, you cannot store object references in a database, nor can you store them in a file or any other place that is outside of the JVM's storage.  You *can* store some representation of an object (eg, JSON or XML or a "serialized" object) in a database (including SQLite) or in a file or other "offline" storage.